# sum multiple columns from one table

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql table have 4 columns (product1,sample1,peoduct2,sample) I want to make query to get the sum of cells on sample1 & sample32 where product1 or product2 = 4

I use

```
$query="SELECT (SELECT SUM(sample1) FROM table WHERE product1= 4) + (SELECT SUM(sample2) FROM table WHERE product2 = 4)  AS SumCount";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <td>
    echo $row[1];           
}

    product1       sample1        product2     sample2
-------------  -----------      -----------   ----------- 
5                 1                  3            5   
7                 3                  4            6
4                 7                  8            7
10                8                  9            9
4                 2                  2            8
2                 5                  2            8
```

the results should be for value 4 (7 + 2 + 6) but i make loop for all products like this

4   15
2   21

but it give me 1 row not multi rows products

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional statements inside of `sum` expressions, like this:

```
select sum((case when product1 = 4 then sample1 else 0 end) + (case when product2 = 4 then sample2 else 0 end)) total
  from stuff
    where product1 = 4 or product2 = 4;
```

If you want to see the values being summed on individual rows, just remove the `sum`, and use this:

```
select (case when product1 = 4 then sample1 else 0 end) + (case when product2 = 4 then sample2 else 0 end) total
  from stuff
    where product1 = 4 or product2 = 4;
```

If you actually want it to show the addition formula, you can use `group_concat` with `+` as the separator, like this:

```
select group_concat((case when product1 = 4 then sample1 else 0 end) + (case when product2 = 4 then sample2 else 0 end) separator '+') total
  from stuff
    where product1 = 4 or product2 = 4;
```

Here's an example fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbf57/4

(note, if both product1 and product2 are 4, then this will include sample1 and sample2 for those, so product1 = 4, sample1 = 5, product2 = 4, sample2 = 9 would add 14 to the count).

If i still haven't arrived at the output you were expecting (you didnt give an example of how you would like the output to look), let me know and i'll make further updates.

**update based on comments**

I think this may finally be what you want. To get the sums of samples for ALL products, an easy way is to create a temporary table that combines all product1/sample1, product2/sample2 into a single product/sample table, and then group by the combined product field to sum the combined sample values.

```
select product, sum(sample) total
  from
    (select product1 as product, sample1 as sample
       from stuff
     union all
     select product2 as product, sample2 as sample
       from stuff
    ) q1
    group by product
```

[updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbf57/7)

Comment: plus one, Useful solutions indeed. :)

Comment: it should show that if value = 4 so will be  7 + 2 + 6 , if be 2  will be 5+8+8

Comment: yes, but should the query result be `15`, `7 + 2 + 6` or `7, 2, 6` in individual rows?

Comment: you want to do this for all products at once?

Comment: Iwant get the sum of the samples of every producte from columns sample1 & sample 2